# iPhone - Differing free memory reports

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iPhone 6 running iOS 11.4.1. When I go to Settings/About, it tells me I have 32 Gigs available in my 64 Gig iPhone. When I use iExplorer, it lists on the screen that my 64 Gig iPhone has only 14.6 Gigs. Since these values are so different I'm asking if either one is correct. I'm tempted to believe what my iPhone says but why such a difference?